# How do I add a textbox for my configurable products?

Tags: products

Is there a option to add a textbox? The user should create his own text for his t-shirt. I only know how to add a dropdown menu.

Comment: use custom option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can ***add custom option for text box to the configurable product***.

Refer this [**Link**](http://insync.co.in/how-to-create-custom-options-configurable-products-in-magento/). You will get better understanding of product custom option.